# Unable to retrieve and store the details of the caller during the ringer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to store the caller's detail -- name, number and time -- in 3 different arraylists, while the phone is still ringing. If the caller's not in contacts, the name stored is "Name unavailable." Here's the code -

```
        //code from the onReceive() function.
        getDetails(name, inNumber);
        telephonyService.endCall();
        openWhatsAppContact(inNumber, mContext);

        saveLogName.edit().putString("logName", TextUtils.join(",", logName)).apply();
        saveLogNumber.edit().putString("logNumber", TextUtils.join(",", logNumber)).apply();
        saveLogTime.edit().putString("logTime", TextUtils.join(",", logTime)).apply();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void getDetails(String name, String number){
    if(name == "?"){
        logName.add("Name unavailable");
    }else{
        logName.add(name);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, TextUtils.join(",", logName));
    logNumber.add(number);
    Log.d(TAG, TextUtils.join(",", logNumber));
    Time now = new Time();
    now.setToNow();
    logTime.add(now.toString());
    Log.d(TAG, TextUtils.join(",", logTime));
}
```

On calling `getDetails()`, nothing happens, I know this because of the log statements within the function. Also, none of the code after the call of `getDetails()` is implemented. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

AndroidManifest permissions -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Did you set the manifest permissions ? can i see the permissions ?

Comment: @j2emanue Done. The code worked fine before I added the `getDetails()` function. It rejected the calls as desired. I've edited the description and added the permissions, as you asked.

Comment: did you end up fixing it ?

Answer (score 1):

your doing the wrong test to compare strings ..you should use '**equal**' instead of ==

do it like this:

```
 if(name!=null && name.equals.("?")){
        logName.add("Name unavailable");
    }else{
        logName.add(name);
    }
```

Comment: tip: `if("?".equals(name))` removes need for `null` check